# HighlightGraph and Hyperlink

Tags: bugs, graphs-and-networks, hyperlink

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and fixed in 10.0**

---

In the documentation of *Mathematica* it is mentioned that you can use `Hyperlink` and `Tooltip` as *wrapper* in a  similar manner as `Style`. However, the following example  does not seem to work:
vertices `1` and `2` are highlighted in `Red` but there is neither hyperlink access nor tip.

```
HighlightGraph[Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3}], {Tooltip[1, "TEST IT!"], 
                 Hyperlink[2, "http://stackexchange.com/"]}]
```

Did I miss something ?

Comment: I have to evaluate the Output to make it work: [see here](http://i.imgur.com/oSVQRYa.gif). Windows7 V9.01.

Comment: Thank you. However in your demo, you have validated the output of the code line to enable the hyperlink, and effectively it works. I don't understand why two validations are required ?

Comment: More comments should come with more feedback :)

Comment: Same issue with `Graph[{Property[1, Tooltip -> "Test"], 
  Property[2, Hyperlink -> "http://stackexchange.com/"]}, {1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 3}]` using V9.0.1 on Windows 7.

Comment: I'm prepared to call this a bug. BTW It is an interesting exercise to open up the original graph output and Öskå's version (the evaluated graph) using ctrl-shift-E and look  for the differences.

Comment: Thank you for your feedbacks, effectively there exists a difference and the mouse clicked cannot be trapped with the first output. Hence, I am a bit puzzled on the ability to produce the right result once the output is validated since no element on the code indicates the existence of hyperlinks.

Comment: `Properties -> {1 -> {Hyperlink -> "http://stackexchange.com/"}}}]]` is (part of) what I see using ctrl-shift-E with the first Output; this is there on the second Output after evaluating the Output, as well as a an `EventHandler` expression missing from the first Output.

Comment: Same story with the `Button[...]` wrapper which I was about to post a question about.  If this isn't a bug, I'm not sure what would count as one.  I also tried to `Evaluate` the graph once created using `Evaluate[%]` but that, unsurprisingly, didn't help.

Answer (score 6):

This works correctly in version 10.0 and later.